# Help understanding polar coordinates and conversion between polar and rectangular

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I'm not understand this. I understand that you can take normal functions with x's and y's and convert them into polar coordinates. I also understand that the polar form of that function will have the same exact graph because your getting the same points just a different way. What I do not get is this, if you take something like y=2x and just replace the x with θ and take the y and replace it with r, you will get the same exact outputs for he same inputs but the groans look completely different. Is this called something special? I don't get this because the way I see it, you can take functions like the one above and convert them into polar form(which just gives us the same graph because like I said it's just getting the inputs and outputs a different way) and then there's this thing that we can do by replacing the x with θ and the y with r. Are these two separate things? What's going on!?

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert something from rectangular to polar, convert $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ Also, $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

The way the rectangular coordinate system works is that for each point, you define it's displacement vertically and horizontally from the origin. So suppose point (1,2) would be 1 unit to the right and 2 units up.

The way the polar coordinate system works is that for each point, you define an angle to point at, with $\theta=0$ at the positive $x$-axis, and the distance from the origin. So for example, ($\pi/4$,5) would be a point 5 units away from the origin pointing at the direction $\pi/4$.

The conversions from rectangular to polar coordinates are illustrated below:
[image]

EDIT: To answer more:
Converted $y=2x$ to $r=2\theta$ doesn't really mean anything. For the second equation, you are saying that you want the distance from the origin to be twice the radians that you are facing from the center. You graph these equations in different ways. The image below shows how to graph polar graphs:

[image]

In conclusion, $x$ and $y$ are just arbritary variables, as are $\theta$ and $r$. What is important is how you define them in terms of plotting them. Generally, we use $x,y$ for rectangular plots, and we use $r,\theta$ for polar graphs. They are completely different ways of graphhing things.

Comment: I know this but what is going on where when you switch the x for θ and the y for r, you get a graph that's not the same but the inputs and outputs match.

Comment: @KingSquirrel I edited my answer. Does this help at all?

Comment: Well do you see though that the graphs are not the same but they have the same input to output. Like y=x+1 and r=θ+1. The latter function gives the same outputs for inputs as the first function but the graphs are much different. This isn't the converted polar form of the first function but something else, does this have a name?

Comment: @KingSquirrel The very last paragraph of my answer kind of explains that. There really isn't an name for that because operations like that are not useful in mathematics. You graph things in polar because they are much easier to graph in polar or they are more convenient. However, I cannot think of a scenario where you have an equation with rectangular coordinates and you just replace the x's with r's and etc, because it simply just does not make sense. It is useless to us.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. This is what I suspected. I didn't see any reason to do it either. It just appeared that if we replace the x with θ and the y with r, then the graph has the same output for each input but the graph is different but I guess it is just a coincidence that has no use.